# Where is the best place to ask for recommendations?

Tags: discussion

The Stack Overflow FAQ lists the following type of questions as *off-topic*:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem  and what has been done so far to solve it.

But dammit, these kind of questions come up a lot, and I don't care if I get opinionated answers. If I'm searching for the best tool to do some sort of task I want people to tell me all the best options, and I don't mind if they're opinionated about it. That just signals to me that they have a good reason for pushing for one software library over another.

Plus, Yahoo Answers frankly isn't going to get the same caliber of people answering questions about software libraries. Whereas the folks that frequent Stack Overflow *will* know that stuff. I want to ask *them* about what's the best syntax highlighting plugin, for instance. Is there any Stack Exchange site that does allow these sorts of questions?

Comment: Yahoo! Answers doesn't get the same caliber of people answering questions because we enforce site rules and quality standards and they don't.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) accepts recommendation questions (obviously). Software libraries are explicitly on-topic there (or at least they used to be, their on-topic page changed since I last looked at it).

**Important meta post from their site, please read before asking**: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea that existed until right now. Thank you! I think perhaps that should be linked to explicitly [in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @SoaperGEM I don't know about that, we want people to be careful when asking questions. Pretty much every "migration" comment should always have the "Check their on-topic/meta" disclaimer, because many of us aren't active on that site. Also, most recommendation questions are total crap anyways, no need to inundate them with it.

Comment: You might want to stress that the linked meta post absolutely should be read *before posting there*. Otherwise, people are going to read your first paragraph and run to SoftwareRecs without even seeing the second one.

Comment: @SoaperGEM the volume that Stack Overflow can redirect to other sites (even via the FAQ) is such that, well, on anything other than the other big ones it can completely inundate them.  If they don't have the capability to moderate active enough (enough high rep users) 30 posts/day sent there can double or triple the daily questions - and not enough close votes or down votes or delete votes... it can be bad. You should check with the other site before asking to add it to the FAQ here.